# What norms are followed when one president (or head of state) calls another?

Tags: international-relations

**Introduction:**

- I often read news which says one president or prime minister calls a president or prime minister of another country.
- I assume the process is something like: someone (maybe a secretary) schedules the phone call. Once allowed the party wanting to call calls the other party. There might be a group of people accompanying the President or Prime Minister, with at least a translator (for bi-lingual situations) during the phone call.
- I also assume even though there are lots of countries, which may or may not have specific protocols for government-to-government calls, at least part of the process could have some common protocols. Also, these protocols might be part of *diplomat training programmes.*

Now, the points above are just assumptions.

**Question:**

What are the general norms that are followed before and during such phone calls?

Note: If answers are specific to a particular country, it's fine. As mentioned earlier, I presume the process might not differ much from country to country.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered. It probably depends a lot on the relationship between the indiviidual people and their countries. Also on the topic to be discussed and the general political context.  Surely the arrangements for Trump/Jong-Un will be different to Trump/Johnson or Xi/Jong Un  or Trump/Xi   etc etc.

Comment: Hypothesis: this process is not transparent, because the governments involved rely on security-by-obscurity to avoid every troll on the internet trying to prank-call heads of state impersonating other heads of state.